# Keep current line in same position when toggling folds (zi)?

Tags: folding, scrolling

When toggling folds with <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>, any folds expanding above the current line cause the current line to disorientingly jump to a different place on the screen.

How can I keep the current line fixed in the same place while toggling folds?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a mapping and use it instead of using zi. Create a mark for the current position and one for the top of the visible buffer, apply zi, move to the top, move the buffer, then move back to the original position.

```
nnoremap <Leader>zi maHmb'azi'bzt`a
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `zi` you should use `zo` to open a fold and `zc` to close it or `za` to toggle the fold. These commands never make the current line jump for me.

Note that these commands have a recursive equivalent: `zC`, `zO` and `zA`

See

- [`:h zo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#zo)
- [`:h zc`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#zc)
- [`:h za`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#za)

Comment: Sure, but sometimes I want additional context from surrounding code and just want to temporarily dismiss all folds. Going around and manually opening nearby folds with zA wouldn't cause unexpected jumps, but it would undoubtedly take a lot more keystrokes.

Comment: @gandalf3 Oh I didn't understood your use case properly. I'm not sure you'll get a good solution: `zR` and `zM` seems to move the current line too so you might have to write a function which will save the position, handle the folds and restore the position back.